# Hide tooltips in Colorbox / Justified Gallery

Tags: jquery, tooltip, gallery, colorbox

I'm using Justified Gallery to make an image array (http://miromannino.com/projects/justified-gallery/comment-page-3/#comment-73055). A "title" text is given for the Colorbox caption, and an "img alt" text for the thumbnail caption.

I would really like to turn off the tooltips as they are annoying and duplicate the thumbnail caption, but I can't delete the title text without deleting the Colorbox captions, which are different.

Here's a code snippet:

```
<a href="images/pics/Head-Smashed-in-Ft-Mcleod.jpg" title="<strong>Head Smashed In,
Ft. McLeod &#8250; August 2007.</strong> There really is a Head-Smashed-In Park to
commemorate the native buffalo hunts.">
   <img alt="Head Smashed In, Ft. McLeod &#8250;
   August 2007." src="images/thumbs/Head-Smashed-in-Ft-Mcleod.jpg" />
</a>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myGallery").justifiedGallery({
    'justifyLastRow':false, 
    'rowHeight':180, 
    'rel':'gallery2',
    'margins':0,
    'onComplete': function(gal) {
        $(gal).find("a").colorbox({
            maxWidth : "80%",
            maxHeight : "80%",
            opacity : 0.8,
            overlayClose: "true",
            transition : "elastic",
            current : ""
        });     
    }
}); 

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the setting: `caption`.

`$("#myGallery").justifiedGallery({
    'justifyLastRow':false, 
    'rowHeight':180, 
    'rel':'gallery2',
    'margins':0,
    'captions':false,
    'onComplete': function(gal) {
        $(gal).find("a").colorbox({
            maxWidth : "80%",
            maxHeight : "80%",
            opacity : 0.8,
            overlayClose: "true",
            transition : "elastic",
            current : ""
        });

    }
});`